# Profiling SharePoint 2010 with Red Gate ANTS Profiler

Tags: publishing-site, performance

I'm trying to profile my customized SharePoint 2010 site with Red Gate ANTS Profiler, but I can't get it to work.

I've followed every guide I could find, including [the official guide](http://www.red-gate.com/support/Knowledgebase/ANTS_Profiler/AP4SharePoint.pdf), but I'm just getting blank pages with 500 HTTP status codes when browsing the profiled site. It doesn't seem to matter which credentials I use or who the primary Site Collection Administrator is.

Has anyone gotten it to work? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't support sharepoint 2010:

[Profiling SharePoint](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content?p=ANTS%20Performance%20Profiler&c=ANTS_Performance_Profiler/help/6.2/app_sharepoint.htm&toc=ANTS_Performance_Profiler/help/6.2/toc1408011.htm)

Comment: Oh. Is there any profiler that does?

Answer (score 1):

We have since worked on this and are starting to provide documentation for ANTS to profile Sharepoint 2010. For example:

[Profiling Sharepoint 2010](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content?p=ANTS%20Memory%20Profiler&c=ANTS_Memory_Profiler%5Cknowledgebase%5Camp_sharepoint_2010.htm)